# DBT incremental models - Is there a way to keep track of the "updated" timestamp?

Tags: dbt

Is there a way to create an incremental model with dbt and update the timestamp if a new row was added or an existing row was updated, but not if the row remains unchanged?

Have tried changing stategies, nothing avails.

Comment: Could you add a brief example of some source data and what you want your output table to look like, please? I'm not 100% certain what you mean by 'the timestamp' here. In case it turns out to be relevant, it would also be useful to know what data warehouse you are using.

Comment: It also sounds like you're talking about a snapshot, not an incremental model?